# using office url referrer to open word file directly from browser

Tags: html, windows, url, referrer

I am using office url referrer “ofe ms-word:nft|u|http://…” to open word file directly from browser.

If I use the “http://localhost/Berry.WebApp4/xxx/xxx/xxx/1655e91c-8205-4137-ba61-bbc5e99ed0a5.docx” url without office url referre the file downloads correctly and I can open it using Microsoft word, but if I use the same url to open the clinet word directly from browser:
“ms-word:ofe|u|http://localhost/Berry.WebApp4/xxx/xxx/xxx/1655e91c-8205-4137-ba61-bbc5e99ed0a5.docx” then Microsoft word gives the following message:

```
word found unreadable content in login. do you want to recover 
the contents of the document ? 
if you trust the source of the document click yes
```

And even if I click yes the recovery operation also fails.

Comment: Please re-word your question as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was because the action has [authorize] tag where i required authentication but when Ms Word tries to open the file there was no authentication header in the request.